# Properly displaying an array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

Below is my code. I'm trying to display some data as an array drawing from a SQL server. The problem is when I get to `foreach` I can't seem to get it to display the data correctly and it either keep repeating the data or just doesn't display it.  I apologize if this questions seems basic I am a noob to programming and from what I have have researched I think I need to change my `writeline` to a write and potentially do another for loop....just not entirely sure any suggestions would help.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connection = "Data Source=INIWS64-04;Initial Catalog=INEW18_2013;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; User ID=recordsadmin;Password=security";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string Sql = "";
            Sql = "select * from qryEDocRequest order by Request_ID";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(table);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
                        for (int w = 0; w < table.Columns.Count; ++w)
                        {
                            StringBuilder array = new StringBuilder();
                            foreach (Char Item in row.ItemArray.ToString())
                            {
                                array.Append(Item + ",");
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine(array);


                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception Test)
                {
                    throw Test;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your `for (char l = 0;.....`?

Comment: whoops I put in the wrong code I had a foreach there  
  foreach (Char Item in row.ItemArray.ToString())
                            {
                                array.Append(Item + ",");
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine(array);

Comment: I updated it with the correct one.... I was experimenting with another for loop when I decided to ask the question..... sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a lot easier way to do what you are trying to do:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
{
    adapter.Fill(table);
}

foreach(var row in table.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based off of your response I was able to resolve using the foreach as follows

```
{
adapter.Fill(table);
}
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
}
```

Thanks so much this was the simplest way